# Increase discoverability of collapse/expand function in achievements dialog

Tags: feature-request, achievements-dialog, user-experience

This morning I discovered by accident that you can click on the headers ('Today', 'Yesterday', 'Last 7 days') in the achievements dialog to collapse them:

[image: partly collapsed achievements​ dropdown]

Can something be done to increase the discoverability of this feature? Yes, the cursor changes to a 'hand' when hovering over it, so I should have known it's clickable, but a tooltip would be nice as well. I'm open for other/better ideas as well.

Comment: Pretty sure it's new. :) (I usually click a lot of stuff just to check what happens)

Comment: @Shadow9 how young does it have to be to be "new"? I've seen that feature for several weeks (months?), I think

Comment: @Jenayah year old features are considered "new" in my personal SE dictionary. ;)

Comment: You can do *what*? I guess it's true what they say - a feature that users can't easily find may as well not exist...

Answer (score 14):

In addition to a tooltip, some arrows preceding the headers would help, as we've become trained to recognize them as indicators of the presence of a dropdown.

Something like this, or my very crappy drawn-on-my-phone sketch below:

> ▶ Collapsed menu #1
>
> ▶ Collapsed menu #2
>
> Expanded menu #3
>
> - list item #1
> - list item #2
>
> [image: hand-drawn sketch of the above]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLgXB.png

Comment: no freehand circle?

Comment: This is *gorgeous* drawing. 5/7 way better than literally all mockups I've ever been given.

Comment: @Luuklag the hand drawn arrows are close enough to a circles, if you ask me. (Just joking, love the design)